# Unique extendable functions... Is there a theory?

Tags: real-analysis, category-theory

*Motivation*: Take a continuous function $f$ from a topological space $X$ to a hausdorff space $Y$. If $g$ is a continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ that coincides with $f$ in a dense set, then $g=f$.

Take an analytic function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. If $g$ is an analytic function that coincides with $f$ in a set with limit point, then $g=f$.

Okay, now given the motivation, my question is the following:

**Is there a theory which has the objective of characterizing functions that satisfy a certain "unique extension" property, in a general context?**

For example, we could define:

> Definition: Given a family $\mathcal{F} $ of maps $f:X \rightarrow Y$ , $f \in \mathcal{F}$ is said to satisfy *$P$-unique-extendability on $(X,Y)$* if for every subset $A \subset X$ which satisfies the property $P$, we have that every function $g \in \mathcal{F}$ which coincides with $f$ in $A$ is such that $f=g$.

Therefore, for example, every continuous function is *dense-unique-extendable on $(\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R})$*

Maybe there is a categorical POV of this?

Comment: I would suggest changing the title to something like "uniquely extendable functions" instead of just "extendable".

Comment: Agreed --------

Comment: really interesting, I wonder if theory of this kind could help in the field of fractional/complex iteration (extension of the number iterations from naturals/integers to other domains ).

Comment: "Therefore, for example, every continuous function is dense-extendable on (ℝ, ℝ)". Of course it is. Just define it arbirtrarily off the dense set.

Comment: I corrected the definition, since it was wrong... but I don't get your point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is strongly connected to the notion of an [epimorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism). In the category of Hausdorff spaces, the epimorphisms are those continuous maps with dense image. In the category of smooth manifolds, the epimorphisms have the same description; but this can be simplified because of the identity theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume your class of morphisms is closed under composition, contains identities, and inclusions of subobjects you're interested in, so that we can place all this into a single category, then properties of extensions translate to elementary properties of the $\mathrm{Hom}$ functor.

Let $f : A → B$ be a morphism (an inclusion of a subspace $A ⊆ X$ you mentioned would be a motivating example) and say that morphisms from $B$ to $C$ are uniquely determined on $f$ if all morphisms $g$, $h : A → C$ that agree on $f$ (ie. $gf = hf$) are in fact equal. In other words, this is exactly saying that $\mathrm{Hom}(f, C)$ is an injective function, so we're basically asking when is this the case.

As Martin Brandenburg notes, it is obviously true if $f$ is an epimorphism (more abstractly, hom functors preserve monos, so the contravariant one translates epis to injections). Since you are primarily interested in subobjects, in your case $f$ would in fact be a bimorphism. This of course is not necessary: even if morphisms to $C$ are determined on $f$, morphisms to $D$ needn't be (in other words: hom-functors don't necessarily reflect monos). One way to ensure that epicness is necessary is to demand that $C$ be a cogenerator, ie. that for every pair $f$, $g : X → Y$ of distinct parallel morphisms there exists a morphism $h : Y → C$ that distinguishes them ($hg ≠ hf$). An example of a cogenerator is the unit interval for functionally Hausdorff or better spaces. This is awfully restrictive, but I don't think there's much more you can say in such a specific situation where both $f$ and $C$ are fixed.
Of course if you allow $C$ to vary then you get exactly the definition of an epimorphism.

ps. I changed your "uniquely extendable through f" to "uniquely determined on f", because I think "unique extendability" should imply extendability, which is not the case here:
every ring morphism $\mathbb Q → \mathbb Z/(5)$ is trivially uniquely determined on $\mathbb Z → \mathbb Q$, but no morphism $\mathbb Z → \mathbb Z/(5)$ can be extended to $\mathbb Q$.
Note that extendability also has an easy categorical formulation: saying that every morphism $g : A → C$ extends through $f : A → B$ is exactly asking for the function $\mathrm{Hom}(f, C)$ to be surjective. Unique extendability would then correspond to that function being bijective. Existence of extensions is a more difficult problem because in general hom functors neither preserve nor reflect epis. Two ways to ensure the extensions exist would be demanding that $f$ be a split mono, so that $A$ is a retract of $B$, or that $C$ be an injective object, but both of these are overkills (although the first one is exactly what you need if you allow $C$ to be arbitrary).